# TrueNAS: Can read/write through SMB but not FTP

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, smb, freenas, truenas

I have a small TrueNAS server set up and I can access my files over SMB. I want to access it through the internet to I want to access it via FTP as well. FTP successfully connects but I cannot read/write to any of the files.
I am guessing that I have something wrong with the permissions my users and groups?

I can give any details required but there are so many I could give but I don't know which ones so please let me know what details to post here.

Things I have done already:

- Tested on Mac, Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04
- Added FTP group to the user
- Set all folders to Read Write Execute in FTP settings
- Tried setting Read Write Execute to all of the users home folder
- Create a group called ftpuser and add it to the desired user

permissions

**edit:**
I should also note that when i say read/write, I can still see the files but I cannot open them and edit them. e.g. I can see an image file, but I cannot open it. on a Mac it just says "Preview was unable to open this file."

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestions? 3 days now.

Comment: Anybody? Over a week now.